# Pandas vectorized DateOffset

Tags: pandas, datetime

I want to add a DateOffset to a datetime column in Pandas, where the values of the date offset are integers from another column, in a vectorized way. I also need it to use calendar arithmetic, not absolute time deltas.

I've tried:

`df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b'].apply(lambda x: pd.DateOffset(months=x))`

Where column 'a' contains datetimes and column 'b' contains integers representing months.

But this throws: `performancewarning: adding/subtracting object-dtype array to datetimearray not vectorized`

Is there a fully vectorized way to do this using Pandas or Numpy, which still uses calendar arithmetic?

Comment: Please include a minimal relevant dataframe, as a dictionary to be copy pasted and reproduced easily.

Comment: What is the size of `df` and how many different value you have in `df['b']`?

Comment: The df's i'm working could be as large as 10,000 rows x 200 cols, where the date col is just various dates and the months col is random ints in the 1-300 range

Comment: No, i'm applying a date offset to column a, which is dates. Using apply on the int column transforms the ints into DateOffset objects.

Comment: I found an answer for you here: [PerformanceWarning when adding months to datetime values in Pandas DataFrame using apply() and DateOffset](https://py4u.org/questions/75762895/)